# Android WebView takes ~10s to fire DOMContentLoaded

Tags: javascript, android, performance, webview, android-webview

I am developing an app that loads a website in a WebView, and I'd like to run some custom JS to hide certain elements from the page before showing.

In order to make sure that the html is fully parsed and loaded before hiding elements, I am injecting the following JS to my WebView's `onPageCommitVisible` callback:

```
function myJsFunction() { ... }
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myJsFunction);
```

which works fine on high-end devices (Samsung S22, Pixel 7), but `DOMContentLoaded` takes ~10s to fire on lower end devices like the Samsung A13...

Is this normal? Is there anything I can do to speed up the DOM loading?

Thank you in advance for taking a look!